# What is causing a power cutoff on this board after 10 seconds?

Tags: power-supply, led-driver

I have identified this board as a Lorikeet LED-2 board. It runs very well on its platform which I have tested and the power supplied to it is 7.0V. I cannot use this LED with its original power supply and need to run it from a different source.

[image: LEDs circuit board] [image: LEDs power requirements]

I crafted a small circuit to tune down my 12V power supply to meet its requirement, currently. I can supply 7.1V to the board using a number of components as indicated in the sketched circuit.

[image: Circut to step down 12v to 7v using LM7505]

The LEDs shut down after ~10 secs every time I turn them on.

I have tried with another source with 6.4V but I get the same behavior.

What could be happening here? Is there a way I can modify this circuit and bypass any checks and have them run without frying them?

Comment: Did you try increasing the supply voltage (by adding one or two more diodes in series with D1, D2, and D3)? The IC supplying the LEDs can run from 5 V to 36 V, so you might be able to run it directly at 12 V, but I need to look more at the complete layout, as there may be something else limiting the input voltage.

Comment: Did you try using somewhat larger input and output capacitor values on the 7805 regulator, such as 330 nF to 1 uF?

Comment: What's the yellow wire for, some switch? Did you use it or connected it in any way? There is a PIC12F MCU onboard, the software could do anything.

Comment: @EdinFifić I have not tried to input voltage more that the stated 7.2v.

Comment: @Justme the yellow wire connects to a push button switch. Its circuit is complete with the switch and has a power jack, which is what I use to supply the voltage.  Also, it has two levels of intensity, first press lights it up, second one increases the intensity. About the MCU, I was thinking maybe it has to be reprogrammed - but only if I can read what it is currently instructed to do.

Comment: (I trust there is a dot missing in the sketch immediately above the GND symbol.) Please add to the question whether the voltage regulator is indeed a TO220 - it dissipates almost 1 W.

Comment: @greybeard the voltage regulator is LM340T5 7805.

Comment: U2 is a [SD42560 buck converter](http://www.datasheet-pdf.com/PDF/SD42560-Datasheet-SilanMicroelectronics-927264), apparently in a constant current configuration with coil, big cap, diode and 1-ohm current-sense resistor R4. This chip has a Vin of 40V ... is it possible you don't need to supply 7V to it and it would accept higher? It seems a shame to be feeding a switched controller with a linear regulator.  (I see also U3,  AD7330, 3V 300mA linear reg, seemingly fed from L1/D2, for CPU.)

Comment: @jonathanjo - The 3V is for the PIC 12F1501, it looks like the StepUp-regulator would run with 12V directly too.

Comment: @jonathanjo on the power requirements, for better context, here are the images for front, back of the original power supply and the battery. 

The battery is 6.4v. On the power jack, I tested the output voltage(going to the leds) and it is 7.0v.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hg3BDrRmyIkikN4OX2uDRGEp4tmAXYzc?usp=share_link

Comment: @KEKeronei - Hi, (a) Just to be clear: Are you saying that the LEDs work fine with the original power supply, but (for a reason which I haven't seen explained) you cannot use that power supply in your application, and are trying to design another power supply - is that correct? (b) Why do you say there is a "power cutoff" after 10 seconds? Have you measured the new power supply output and it really does drop to zero after 10 s? Or do you mean the new power supply output does *not* drop to zero after 10 s, but the LEDs stop emitting light? Please clarify by making an [edit] to the question.

Comment: To @SamGibson,
a) The LEDs work fine with their original power.

b) The LEDs go off after 10 secs - they stop emitting light, I even connected the voltmeter in parallel and observed that there was no voltage drop from the power supply. 

For the avoidance of doubt, I have two of these LED boards and they have the same behavior.

Comment: @MikroPower indeed, it's described as buck/boost/buck-boost: and I'm sure you are correct that it's in boost mode to feed the LEDs in a single chain.

Comment: @KEKeronei - Thanks for your reply. Last question from me for now: Your [photos on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hg3BDrRmyIkikN4OX2uDRGEp4tmAXYzc?usp=share_link) show the original power source is a 2S1P LiFePO4 battery pack (so presumably max 7.2 V, nominal 6.4 V) but it shows a complicated PCB, not the simple-ish LED bulb you are holding in the original photos. What is the relationship between that newly-disclosed complicated PCB with LCD display, GSM module, MCU etc. and the simple-ish LED bulb? It seems the situation is much more complicated than originally described

Comment: @SamGibson The later images show the (original)circuit that supplies the voltage to the LEDs. The image I have lebelled "Power Jack" is where the power cord going to the LEDs is connected. 

It comes with 3 of those LED boads as "bulbs". From this unit, only two wires connect it with the board I have atteched to the question, which gives me some guarantee that it only supplies power, meaning I can change the source of power and it can be well powered.

Comment: It is possible, that you need a bulk capacitor >= 100 µF at the input side of the LED board. The original supply may contain such a cap to provide the pulsed current while your linear regulator circuit with C2 = 100 nF is too weak (or slow) and causes voltage ringing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SD42560E is a StepUp converter, the LEDs are all in line (6 x 3V = 18V) and one of the LED has a broken bond wire. This little gold-wire to the LED-chip can break sometimes because of thermal stress.

After it reaches the temperature the connection is lost and the lamp is going off. But it should going on after a while if the temperature of the PCB is going down enough.

Way to find the error:

1. It the Lamp is off after this 10 seconds, you can bridge one of the LEDs with a tweezer (you connect + and - of the LED with metal and then the current can flow around the LED, then the current do not need to flow through the LED) and if the Lamp is going on, then this is the LED with the broken bond-wire. If nothing is happening, then remove the tweezer and bridge the second LED, third LED ... and so on. And do not look directly into the LED-light, cover the other LEDs with paper. I use a piece of paper with a hole if I try to find the damaged LED.
2. Mostly only one of the LEDs is broken.If you have found the broken LED, then you can bridge them with a wire. (the new type of LEDs are "flip-chip"-LEDs, they do not have bond wires any more, they are soldered directly onto the board)
3. If you have tried every LED with the bridge-methode, then the error is possibly somewhere close to the switching regulator. And never bridge more than 3 LEDs at the same time, because you have 7.1V input voltage and 3 white  LEDs do need between (minimum: 2.4V*3=)7.2V and (maximum: 3V*3=)9V. This means, 3 LEDs must be without bridge.

You have less power (only 5 LEDs left), but the current should be the same, because the Silan SD42560E is regulating the current.

You should measure the voltage over the LED, it will be 5* 3V = 15V after the repair, so you can use the 12V power supply. The voltage is regulated up, to around 15V, so you need to supply the Lamp with less then 15V.

Datasheet of the SD42560E Chip: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/927266/SilanMicroelectronics/SD42560E/1

Fix without the microcontroller:

1. You apply 12V to Vin (Pin 8).
2. Pin 6 need a voltage for "dimming", so you can connect Vdd=5V (Pin 7) directly with Pin 6 (PWM-Pin) to have 100% brightness.

Comment: MikroPower - Hi, This point in your answer: "*one of the LED has a broken bond wire*" doesn't make sense to me, as the OP has confirmed that the LEDs work fine with the original power supply. They only go off after 10 s when used with other power supplies. Please can you edit your answer to explain how a broken bond wire would *not* also affect LED behaviour, when using the original power supply? Thanks.

Comment: I have two of these circuit boards with LEDs as "bulbs", they behave the same way. So it is less likely that there is a broken bond wire.

When you mention Pin 8, I presume you are referring to Pad 8. I have tried that and it produces a lot of sparks and does not light, I have tried with the switch, and does not work either.

Comment: @KEKeronei - It is Pin 8, how in the data-sheet described. There should be already 7.1V on this pin if you would attach the wires, so there should not be any sparks. The only target what you must do is to increase the voltage at the PWM-pin (Pin 6) of the SD42560E Chip. Study the data-sheet, I would make a small painting how the connections are and then measure the voltage! Question: Is the voltage at the PWM-Pin 5 Volt at the beginning and is going then after the 10 seconds down to 0V ?

Comment: @SamGibson - This are new information. The PCB looks very good, I could only imagine that the coil must be re-soldered. Two lamps with the same behaviour looks like a condition in the program of the PIC. Possibly the chip is going on, then off and simply waiting for the signal from the button?

Comment: The fix without the controller worked. Connecting 12v to Pin 8 gives high-intensity lighting. On dimming, it does not change the intensity when I connect Pin 7 to 6 but I will take time later to closely read the datasheet. My remaining homework is to enable low intensity, then high intensity subsequently on the push of a button.

Comment: Measure the voltage at pin 6 to GND, if it is 5V, then this is already the maximum brightness.